# Url rewrite rule leads to 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I have this url

```
http://www.mysite.com/product.php?name=Ball&id=25672
```

and i want to make it look like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/Ball-25672/
```

i use this **.htaccess** file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)&id=(.*)
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ /product/%1-%2/? [L,R=301]
```

I have 2 problems:

1) When im scrolling the mouse pointer over the ball item the link that it is displayed on the browser is the 1st but i want it to display the 2nd

2)When i click on the url i get 404 error but the link displayed on the browser is correct.

Comment: _“When im scrolling the mouse pointer over the ball item the link that it is displayed on the browser is the 1st but i want it to display the 2nd”_ – then you will have to write the second one into your HTML …

Comment: mod_rewrite can only redirect your links, it cannot change your page's content.

Comment: @CBroe: And how this link will be processed by the product.php file?

Comment: It will after you rewrite it _internally_ … please go look up how mod_rewrite works, you seem to have no idea.

Comment: @CBroe I've read a lot about it and tried many examples and tools but most of them are propably outdated, i think that im asking something very simple and im not getting an answer.

Comment: If the second URL is what you want to use to request the resource, then there is no query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

> When im scrolling the mouse pointer over the ball item the link that it is displayed on the browser is the 1st but i want it to display the 2nd

The rewrite engine *will not change the actual content of your site*. It only changes request URIs sent by the browser to the server. It's up to you to make your links look like `http://www.mysite.com/product/Ball-25672/` and is completely beyond the ability of mod_rewrite.

Second:

> When i click on the url i get 404 error but the link displayed on the browser is correct.

You are redirecting the browser to the nicer looking URL: `http://www.mysite.com/product/Ball-25672/`. The browser then sees this new URL, *and requests it from the server*. So then the server sees `/product/Ball-25672/` and tries to serve it, and it doesn't exist, thus you get a 404. You need 2 set of rules here, one that externally redirects the browser to the nicer looking URL, then one to internally rewrite the nicer looking URL *back to where the content actually is*:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /+product\.php\?name=([^&]+)&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /product/%2-%3/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^product/(.+)-([0-9]+)/?$ /product.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```